# Codeigniter Form Helper Duplicate from_hidden?

Tags: forms, codeigniter

Im totally stumped.. Im creating some form elements using the CI form helper and for some weird reason, its creating a duplicate version.

Here is my PHP

```
<div id="receiveInventoryItemDetails">

        <p><?php echo form_open('#', array("class" => "nyroModal form label-inline"));?></p>

        <?php echo form_hidden('item_id', '', "readonly = true"); ?>
        <?php echo form_hidden('purchase_order_id', '', "readonly = true"); ?>

        <p><?php echo form_label('Item Name', 'item_name');?><?php echo form_input('item_name', '', "readonly = true"); ?></p>

        <p><?php echo form_label('Item QTY', 'item_qty');?><?php echo form_input('item_qty', ''); ?></p>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
</div>
<div class="buttonrow">
    <button class="btn-sec" onclick="inventoryC.receiveSubmitItem();"><span>Add To Inventory</span></button>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML output

```
<div id="receiveInventoryItemDetails">

    <p><form action="https://mysite.com/#.abl" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="nyroModal form label-inline"></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="purchase_order_id" value="" />

    <p><label for="item_name">Item Name</label><input type="text" name="item_name" value="" readonly = true /></p>

    <p><label for="item_qty">Item QTY</label><input type="text" name="item_qty" value=""  /></p>
    </form>                             
</div>
<div class="buttonrow">
    <button class="btn-sec" onclick="inventoryC.receiveSubmitItem();"><span>Add To Inventory</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use html attributes via third parameter. Look at form helper [source code](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/8f6367e5d338/system/helpers/form_helper.php#cl-120)

This should be work:

```
<?php echo form_hidden('item_id', ''); ?>
```